# Is it possible to change the type of an object by calling a method?

Tags: c++, templates

Template parameters give a lot of power when we avoid side effects (mutation) with respect to what the type describes.

Therefore, it is simple to make something like this:

```
template<size_t N>
String<N+1> append(String<N> s, char c)

String<N> s;
String<N+1> s2 = append(s, 'a')
```

However, to make this operation in place, so that append now would be a method of the class String:

```
template<size_t N>
class String {
     void inplaceAppend(char c) 
};

String<N> s;
s.inplaceAppend('a') # Now s should become of type String<N+1>
```

Is there any workaround to mutate the type of an object at the template parameter level?

Comment: No. An object's type is fixed, it cannot be changed. However you can create a wrapper around `String` class with a, say `void*` member. This member will point to appropriate `String<N>*` type. Then you can mutate it by destroying the old and creating a new member. You would probably have to keep track of `N` as well.

Comment: You can't change the type of anything, ever.

Comment: at least, not without undefined behavior

Comment: A simplest such wrapper is `std::any`.